# How to read HSV values of an image using PIL in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to get the HSV values of all pixels in an image. I tested the below code with a plain magenta image and I got values which are much different from the values  got from a converter online. One more thing I realised is that none of the values of the resultant array are above 255 (Magenta has a H value of approx 300)

```
`from PIL import Image

infile = 'magenta.jpg'
saturation = 0

img = Image.open(infile)
width, height = img.size
img_hsv = img.convert('HSV')

for x in range(width-1):
   for y in range(height-1):
      hsv = img_hsv.getpixel((x,y))
      print(hsv)`
```

Comment: did you consider it may be with different range? lets say everything is `[0 - 255]` ?

Comment: I actually want the HSV values for that pixel. I don't want to set a range

Comment: you are getting the HSV values, but in a range `[0 - 255]`, so hue `0` is red, and hue `255` is also red. Which means you just have to multiply/divide the output value

Comment: Hue values range from 0 - 360 right?

Comment: standard? Yes. That means you have to multiply the output by `(360/255)`

Comment: Oh didn't know that. Thank you so much @Mahrkeenerh

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the "R" value by 360/255, the "G" value by 100/255, and the "B" value by 100/255 to get the respective "H", "S", and "V" values.
Also, when doing an actual image, I've found it easier and more efficient to use the method image.getdata(), instead of looping through every x and y value and using image.getpixel(xy):

```
from PIL import Image

infile = 'example.jpg'

img = Image.open(infile, 'r')
img_hsv = img.convert('HSV')
pixel_array = list(img_hsv.getdata())

hsv_pixel_array = []
for pixel in pixel_array:
    hsv_pixel_array.append(round((pixel[0]*(360/255), 1), round(pixel[1]*(100/255)), round(pixel[2]*(100/255))))

print(hsv_pixel_array)
```